# React hook how to avoid infinite update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to update a property passed down from parent, it's causing infinite loop because I have to include it in the dependency list of useEffect hook.

Example

```
function componentFoo({bar, setBar}) {
    const [baz, setBaz] = useState()
    useEffect(()=>{

        setBar({...bar,baz:baz})
    }, [bar, baz])

    useEffect(()=>{
        setBaz(123)  
    }, [])

    return <>{bar}</>
}
```

How to avoid this?

Comment: you'r setting bar & you have added dependency bar in hooks , so, it will go infinte .remove bar from array in hooks .

Comment: @VyasArpit I do need to know bar's latest value though

Comment: you can add seprate useeffect with bar dependancy and not setBar in that hooks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not add bar as a dependnecy to useEffect since you are updating it within useEffect itself and it will cause an infinite loop.

Instead use a functional approach to setBar like below

```
function componentFoo({bar, setBar}) {
    const [baz, setBaz] = useState()
    useEffect(()=>{

        setBar(prevBar => ({...prevBar,baz:baz}))
    }, [baz])

    useEffect(()=>{
        setBaz(123)  
    }, [])

    return <>{bar}</>
}
```